# Unselectable value in a HTML list

Tags: html

I just discovered this feature in Gmail. In the list where you mark your mails as read or unread, I noticed that there are some values (like **"Apply label:"**, **"Remove label:"**, the separators etc) that cannot be selected. I mean if you click or select them, the list doesn't even close up.

Can anyone tell me how that is achieved? Is there an extra attribute? Javascript? CSS?

I am thinking of doing the same thing to values like **"Select month"** in a list.

Answer (score 2):

Complete rewrite in response to comments:

The options are just `disabled`

Comment: I mean the basic HTML version. Is it supposed to be closed by JS? Is it not HTML-like for the drop-down to roll back up once a value s selected?